# AngularJS : What should my services return to controllers?

Tags: angularjs, service, promise, factory

I'm slowly learning Angular and I'm wondering if my singletons (services & factories) should return a promise object (containing the required data) to my controller or if all promises should be resolved in the factory first and I only pass response.data to my controllers? I've seen both methods used and am wondering what's best practice. Thanks.

Comment: There is no best practice. It depends heavily on the situation at hand. With async data it is usually a good idea to return a promise. But if the data is an array that will be bound to the view, it is also a good idea to return an empty array that later gets filled with the data as they arrive.

Comment: What if the data returned from an async request is an array? I just don't want to be mixing too many different conventions within my controllers.

Comment: ExpertSystem is right on the money.  Also, when using a routing library (I recommend `uiRouter`), you may want to only load a state/route after your services finish loading some data (with `resolve`); in this circumstance, returning a promise from your service is the best bet.

Comment: @NiallO'Brien: A wise man once said: _"With async data it is usually a good idea to return a promise. But if the data is an array [...], it is also a good idea to return an empty array that later gets filled with the data as they arrive."_ It is your right to not want to mix different approaches, but that doesn't make it a good practice :) Different approaches are good for different situation. In a real-world app, you will have different situation, so different approaches will be called for. Consistency is one thing, using the same screwdriver for all kinds of screws is another

Comment: I think both methods are equally valid, and neither one is considered better practice than the other. The great thing about bindings on the scope is that change detection works if the reference changes (and that applies for arrays as well), and also works when you preserve the array reference, but you add/remove/update items in an array bound to ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no best practice. It depends heavily on the situation at hand - different situations/requirements call for different approaches.

As a rule of thumb, with async data it is usually a good idea to return a promise.

Yet, if the data is an array that will be bound to the view (e.g. with an `ngRepeat`), it is also a good idea to return an empty array that later gets filled with the data as they arrive.
This has the benefit that no extra logic is required in the controller.
(BTW, `$resource` uses this approach for its 'GET' methods.)